# How to add reference to PDF files with full text on a MediaWiki website

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I have a MediaWiki website that has about 1000 additional files that are in web directories that are auto-indexed. I'd like those pages to appear in the MediaWiki index. I've come up with two approaches:

1. Write a mediawiki plug-in that creates a page for each directory, with a bulleted list for each item, with a link that downloads the object.
2. Write a python program that uses the mediaWiki API to create a mediawiki page for each item, with full metadata. I can then extract text and put the extracted text on the page as well as MediaWiki preformatted text.

Some of these documents are quite long, however, and so I'm thinking that another approach would be to extract the text from the PDFs and put it into the MediaWiki index. For the multi-page PDFs, it might even make sense to upload (automatically?) a thumbnail of the PDF first page, or even all of the pages.

So what's the appropriate way to reference PDF files with full text on a MediaWiki website?

Answer (score 0):

Use [PdfHandler](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PdfHandler) to expose PDF file metadata to search, and upload those documents as files (using e.g. [Pywikibot](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot) or [importImages.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:ImportImages.php)).